# Javascript works in Firefox, Chrome and Safari but not in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

As the title says.  I have two animated clocks which are simply not moving in IE8
Is there something I am missing here which is affecting the animation in IE?

Clocks:

```
(function(jQuery)
{
  jQuery.fn.clock = function(options)
  {
    var defaults = {
      offset: '+0',
      type: 'analog'
    };
    var _this = this;
    var opts = jQuery.extend(defaults, options);

    setInterval( function() {
      var seconds = jQuery.calcTime(opts.offset).getSeconds();
      if(opts.type=='analog')
      {
        var sdegree = seconds * 6;
        var srotate = "rotate(" + sdegree + "deg)";
        jQuery(_this).find(".sec").css({"-moz-transform" : srotate, "-webkit-transform" : srotate, "-ms-transform" : srotate});
      }
      else
      {
        jQuery(_this).find(".sec").html(seconds);
      }
    }, 1000 );

    setInterval( function() {
      var hours = jQuery.calcTime(opts.offset).getHours();
      var mins = jQuery.calcTime(opts.offset).getMinutes();
      if(opts.type=='analog')
      {
        var hdegree = hours * 30 + (mins / 2);
        var hrotate = "rotate(" + hdegree + "deg)";
        jQuery(_this).find(".hour").css({"-moz-transform" : hrotate, "-webkit-transform" : hrotate, "-ms-transform" : hrotate});
      }
      else
      {
        jQuery(_this).find(".hour").html(hours+':');
      }
      var meridiem = hours<12?'AM':'PM';
      jQuery(_this).find('.meridiem').html(meridiem);
    }, 1000 );

    setInterval( function() {
      var mins = jQuery.calcTime(opts.offset).getMinutes();
      if(opts.type=='analog')
      {
        var mdegree = mins * 6;
        var mrotate = "rotate(" + mdegree + "deg)";        
        jQuery(_this).find(".min").css({"-moz-transform" : mrotate, "-webkit-transform" : mrotate, "-ms-transform" : mrotate});                
      }
      else
      {
        jQuery(_this).find(".min").html(mins+':');
      }
    }, 1000 );
  }
})(jQuery);


jQuery.calcTime = function(offset) {
  d = new Date();
  utc = d.getTime() + (d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
  nd = new Date(utc + (3600000*offset));
  return nd;
};
```

The above code is something I found on the web after spending far to much time trying to get excanvas working correctly in IE

If someone could please correct the errors of my ways, it would be most appreciated.

Edited to only the clock animation issue

Comment: What @type attribute are you using on your script tag?

Comment: @brianary  <script type="text/javascript">

Comment: @Shiplu  Message: Object doesn't support this property or method.  Line: 50  Char: 5  Code: 0  ..  Navigating through the code it seems to be this :  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

Answer (score 1):

talking about IE only, it always just caused by something missing or additional character, it looks one semicolon is missing after the mouseover binding:

```
$('.navlinks img').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).parent().find('img:first').stop().animate({opacity:1}, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Well spotted, I have added the missing semi colon - unfortunately it's still not working

Answer (score 1):

IE doesn't support `transform` property (Only IE9+). If you're working on IE 9 you can add this `-ms-transform`

```
.css({
 "-moz-transform" : mrotate, 
 "-webkit-transform" : mrotate,
 "-ms-transform" : mrotate
});
```

For IE8 It's a bit complicate. You have to use rotation matrix e.g.

```
 // convert to radian first
 var rad = Math.PI/180 * sdegree,
     cos = Math.cos(rad),
     sin = Math.sin(sin); 

'-ms-filter': "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11="+cos+", M12="+(-sin)+", M21="+sin+", M22="+cos+", SizingMethod='auto expand')";
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I have added changed to the original post - is there no other way I could possible get this working with IE 8 and possibly below?

Comment: Thanks again - now the complicated part of implementing this on each of the clock hands..  If could pester you for a little bit of help on that as I am on the brink of a brain meltdown!